# Fatal Error with pip still continuing after solutions

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, python-3.10

Hello Stack Overflow Chads,

So I am trying to run a python file, and I realized it was running in 3.7, but I want it to run it in 3.10, so I uninstalled 3.7, and when i tried installing some libraries it said:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\mailt\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\mailt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

So I went to stack overflow, and I tried doing this:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
python -m pip install -U --force-reinstall pip
```

But I still get this problem. Anyone know whats up?

Comment: Whatever is trying to run your python project thinks it should run Python 3.7. By uninstalling 3.7, you do not teach whatever is running the project to not use 3.7 anymore - it's still trying to do that, it says so when it says it can't find files specified which are in "Python37" directories. What you have done so far is upgrade the python package manager, which is not related to your main issue. Tell us what is the launcher that gives the "Fatal error" at the beginning of your post, and how are you using it? Your goal is to reconfigure that launcher to use Python 3.10 instead of Python 3.7.

Comment: @sinback Im not sure what you mean by launcher, the only command I did was run "pip install" and then a python library into my vs code terminal